# search data in db using textfield flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a DB and I want to make a search system and show data to a screen once a user typed element's title.
Check code below that's how I tried to achieve it
I tried to do this:

```
  Widget searchBar(title) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Task>>(
      future: DBHelper().getTasks(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Task>> snapshot) {
        print('entered'); //does not work
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          var data = snapshot.data;
          print('entered'); //does not work
          return Container(
            child: Column(
              children: data.map((task) {
                print(task.title);
                if (task.title == title) {
                  print('found'); // if user typed correct title than it should print 'found'
                } else {
                  print('not found');
                }
              }).toList(),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

```
  Widget appBar(device) {
    searchAppBar(device) {
      return Expanded(
        child: TextField(
          onChanged: (data) {
            searchBar(data); //pass data to searchBar, data that user passed to an input.
          },

      );
    }

    return Container( 
      child: Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
           searchAppBar(device), // here I display my input
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Added DBHelper().getTasks() method

```
  Future<List<Task>> getTasks() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> maps = await dbClient.query(TABLE, columns: [
      ID,
      NAME,
      TITLE,
      SUBTASKS,
    ]);
    List<Task> tasks = [];
    if (maps.length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
        tasks.add(Task.fromMap(maps[i]));
      }
    }
    return tasks;
  }
```

Code in searchBar was written a few days ago, and it worked and works fine, in this example it does not work):

Comment: can you share DBHelper().getTasks() method looks like?

Comment: @ejabu check it out, but this method does not cause the problem, because this code work fine in another file.